# How to write transient fields to a file in Android?

Tags: java, gson, transient

I am writing my POJO into a file using Gson. I need to benefit from a transient file to manage serialization/deserialization. When I make this field transient, I am unable to write/read it to/from a file. So this fault is originating from Gson settings or File structure in Android? Thanks in advance.

> My Gson:

```
@Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
        return new GsonBuilder()
                .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY)
                .serializeNulls()
                .setLenient()
                .setDateFormat(Constants.GSON_DATE_FORMAT)
                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                .create();
    }
```

> Transient field in POJO

```
@Expose
private transient boolean pdfCreated; --> not visible in the file
```

Comment: But the `transient` keyword is used in Gson (or other serializers) to mark the field to not to be written to file or other serialization techniques. You're defeating the purpose of `transient` then. Why can't you remove the `transient` keyword if you want to serialize it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Darwind and GhostCat now I understand its purpose. I confused by its usage. Thanks for illuminating me :)

Comment: @GhostCat accepted your answer :)

Comment: me, too! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A distinct non-answer here: you are going down the wrong rabbit hole.

Code communicates **intent**. So when you mark fields as `transient`, you are telling your human readers (and all Java tooling) that this field should not be written/read. Whatever value your code puts into that field, you said "I don't care about it, so forget about it when (de)serializing instances of that class".

Thus, the real answer is to step back and use such keywords/annotations the way they are intended to be used.